implement nav2 navigation using d455 realsense camera
I am trying to develop slam with intelRealsense camera d455 for my robot.
I converted the 3d point cloud data to 2d lidar data using depth_to_laser package.
Now i want to develop nav2 but I am confused
for localization. I think amcl is not good choice because realsense has not 360 degree fov and amcl may not work correctly.
Also for odometry data I have wheel encoder and I want to fuse it with realsense imu data. Is it good to fuse realsense imu with odometry to get accurate odometry or use something like rgdb odometry from rtabmap package?
Also for localization in nav2 should I use robot localization package instead of amcl?
And what if I use robot localization, what about map->odom tf?
Will robot localization publish it correctly?
Thank you all
I tried to localize with amcl but didnt work correctly.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
